# Simple query works fine in Oracle 12C but not Oracle 19C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

The following query works fine in our 12C environment but not in our 19C environment.  The 19C returns results but they are ambiguous and include only a subset of the expected results.  See output below.

Note: if I comment out the last two inner joins to my aq_lut_units lookup table(s) the query works fine.

This is a stripped down version of the actual query for fiddling purposes.  Consequently you won't see any reference to the lut columns in the select block.

```
-- SELECT records for three months:
-- TANUSE and TANSRC are ORACLE TYPES.

SELECT
    t.id,
    t.tanid AS tanid,
    t.tanuse.usenmonth AS usenmonth,
    t.tanuse.usesmonth AS usesmonth,
    t.tanuse.usenyear AS usenyear,
    t.tanuse.getGallons(t.tansrc.tanusesubtype) AS THRU_GALLONS
FROM
    aq_uses_tan t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN aq_sources_tan ON t.tanid = aq_sources_tan.id
    INNER JOIN aq_sources ON aq_sources_tan.sourceid = aq_sources.id
    INNER JOIN aq_lut_units su ON su.id = t.tansrc.stand_emfunitsid
    INNER JOIN aq_lut_units tu ON tu.id = t.tansrc.thru_emfunitsid
WHERE
    TO_DATE(t.tanuse.usenyear
              || t.tanuse.usesmonth,'YYYYMM') >= TO_DATE('202201','YYYYMM')
    AND TO_DATE(t.tanuse.usenyear
                  || t.tanuse.usesmonth,'YYYYMM') <= TO_DATE('202203','YYYYMM')
ORDER BY
    t.tanuse.usenyear,
    t.tanuse.usenmonth;
```

```
Expected Results of query in 12C environment:

ID  TANID   USENMONTH   USESMONTH   USENYEAR    THRU_GALLONS
101 1   1   January 2022    4470.89
102 2   1   January 2022    3182
103 3   1   January 2022    0
104 4   1   January 2022    0
105 5   1   January 2022    0
125 5   2   February    2022    0
124 4   2   February    2022    16640.2
123 3   2   February    2022    460.4
121 1   2   February    2022    4671.93
122 2   2   February    2022    2753
144 4   3   March   2022    557.8
143 3   3   March   2022    123
142 2   3   March   2022    3677
141 1   3   March   2022    4851
145 5   3   March   2022    0
```

```
Unexpected Results in 19C environment.
ID  TANID   USENMONTH   USESMONTH   USENYEAR    THRU_GALLONS
121 1   1   January 2022    4470.89
105 5   1   January 2022    0
123 3   1   January 2022    0
124 4   1   January 2022    0
125 5   1   January 2022    0
141 1   1   January 2022    4470.89
142 2   1   January 2022    3182
143 3   1   January 2022    0
144 4   1   January 2022    0
145 5   1   January 2022    0
101 1   1   January 2022    4470.89
102 2   1   January 2022    3182
103 3   1   January 2022    0
104 4   1   January 2022    0
122 2   1   January 2022    3182
```

Comment: We opened and SR ticket with Oracle.  It took a while and in the end Oracle finally recommended that we apply the undocumented parameter "_hash_join_enabled"=false at the session level or as a hint.

My assessment is that there still is a bug somewhere. While we can apply this work around, what about all the other thousands of queries with similar simple joins are waiting to blow up as soon as folks update to 19C?

I hope the Oracle team is actually working on this and will include the fix in a patch or update down the road.